# Intercept initial Ktor authenticate route

Tags: kotlin, oauth-2.0, oauth, ktor

I'm trying to set up ktor oauth to work with GitHub oauth for GitHub App.

I want to authenticate users after installing GitHub App, so
I checked `Request user authorization (OAuth) during installation` checkbox in GitHub config. This feature will take the `Callback URL` and sends initial request to it. The thing is, it has to be the same as `redirect URL` in the oauth process (`urlProvider` in ktor auth config).

My auth config:

```
install(Authentication) {
    oauth("auth-oauth-github") {
        urlProvider = { "$ngrokUrl/gh/oauth/callback" }
        providerLookup = {
            OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
                name = "github",
                authorizeUrl = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize",
                accessTokenUrl = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
                requestMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
                clientId = System.getenv("GITHUB_CLIENT_ID"),
                clientSecret = System.getenv("GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET"),
                passParamsInURL = true,
                defaultScopes = listOf("user:email"),
            )
        }
        client = httpClient
    }
}
```

```
routing {
    authenticate("auth-oauth-github") {
        get("/gh/oauth/callback") {
            // need to check some parameters for initial request
            // and later for the second request need to retrieve principal
        }
    }
}
```

Problem I have is that I had to analyze parameters from the initial request from GitHub, but the ktor auth will automatically redirects to the `authorizeUrl`.

My questions are:

- Can you disable automatic redirects for initial request?
- Can you intercept the initial request to fetch necessary data?

Comment: Can you clarify something for me. What do you mean by initial request? The feature `Request user authorization (OAuth) during installation` is only there for convenience, it just saves a step by asking the user to authorize the app instead of waiting for them to use it for the first time and then ask them to authorize it. It doesn't do anything different than the regular OAuth2 workflow afterwards.

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide WIth this feature GitHub will redirect the user after the installation to the `Callback URL` in the GitHub app settings. This redirect is the `initial request` which I need to process because GitHub sends some additional query params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to disable a redirect to `authorizeUrl` using the `OAuthAuthenticationProvider`. You can add an interceptor for the `authenticate` route to inject your code just before authentication (redirect) happens.

```
authenticate("auth-oauth-github") {
    val phase = PipelinePhase("MyPhase")
    insertPhaseBefore(Authentication.AuthenticatePhase, phase)
    intercept(phase) {
        // Do your processing here
        // call.request contains data for the initial request
    }

    // ...
}
```